# JMeter - Load distribution Testing through Slave Server (NON GUI)

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, master-slave

I am trying to run distributed load on slave machine from Master Server. I have installed all the required Jars on all the system (Servers)
while running test with slave machine getting below exception :

Created the tree successfully using MVP5_multithreading_DryRun.jmx

Configuring remote engine: 10.104.180.51:4000

Starting distributed test with remote engines: [10.104.180.51:4000] @ Mon Sep 18 13:09:28 MYT 2023 (1695013768679)

Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:

```
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Remote engines have been started:[]

The following remote engines have not started:[10.104.180.51:4000]

Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445

1. Jmeter version is same on both master(10.104.180.50) and slave server(10.104.180.51).
2. Required Jars (Concurrency thread group and plug in manager ) files are kept in lib and ext folder of Jmeter on both server.
3. All configuration regarding host and port in properties file of Jmeter has been done.
4. JMX file is uploaded to master server.
5. running the below command
   nohup /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.104.180.50 -n -t MVP5_multithreading_DryRun.jmx  -l MVP5_multithreading_DryRun_20Sep23.jtl -R 10.104.180.51:4000 > MVP5_multithreading_DryRun_20Sep23.log 2>&1 &